# Convert custom date to standard format

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a worksheet that has custom dates e.g.

> August 26th 2015

and I would like to convert this to

> 8/26/15

Is this possible ?

Comment: [How to change date format in Excel and create custom formatting](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/03/11/change-date-format-excel/)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Data tab and click on Text to columns, choose fixed width and click next two times, and in column data format, choose date and select MDY, and click finish. If your date is in A1, they will now be in separate columns- A1 will hold August, B1 will hold 26th and C1 will hold 2015. In D1 type the following:

```
=MONTH(DATEVALUE(A1&"1"))&"/"&LEFT(B1,LEN(B1)-2)&"/"&RIGHT(C1,LEN(C1)-2)
```

output:

```
 8/26/15
```

Or you can download a 60days trial excel tools called [kutools](http://www.extendoffice.com/download/kutools-for-excel.html)

Hope this may help you.

Comment: @AlanBreck If this fully answers your question, please mark it as accepted (green check mark to the left)